# How to remove mouse over effect after clicking on input box

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, typescript

I am working with angular and I have three requirements, There is input box first I have to show a placeholder on pageload like 'TEXT1' which will toggle on mousehover like 'TEXT2 and "TEXT1" and it will change again on mouse focus like 'TEXT3' I achieved it by property binding of placeholder but the problem is after focus hover effect is still on .

How to remove mouse over effect after clicking on input box.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hamsbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Make a stackblitz code and post the link

Comment: use a variable that you changes in the "events" `(mouseover)` `(focus)`  and  `(blur)`. use `[placeholder]="variable"` to show it

Comment: @Eliseo I am using these events but problem is after focusing mouseover event is still working and changes the placeholder

Comment: You can then use two variables: "onfocus" "onmouseover", the events change this variables to true and false -add the event `(mouseout)`. Then  `[placeholder]='"onfocus?'text on focus':onmouseover?'text on mouse over':'text by defect'"`

Comment: @StefaniTotokotsopoulou. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hamsbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Eliseo I have added stackblitz link can you edit and show it

Comment: so u have 1 placeholder text1.. Than u want 2 more variables.  When u hover to be text2 and when to be away from hover to be text3 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  mousein:boolean=false
  focus:boolean=false
  focusText='Text3'
  mouseInText='Text2'
  defaultText = 'Text1';

<input
  type="text"
  [placeholder]="focus?focusText:mousein?mouseInText:defaultText"
  (mouseenter)="mousein=true"
  (mouseleave)="mousein=false"
  (focus)="focus=true"
  (blur)="focus=false"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have here the change for text or color.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hep5pv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html